# Insert a new line after each dot, C++

Tags: c++

I have this code and I want to insert a new line after each dot with a insert statement. I get the error message no matching member function for call to 'insert'. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>


using namespace std;

int main ()
{ 
    string const inText1 = "I'm reading. ";
    string const inText2 = "I like to read. ";
    string const inText3 = "I'm gonna read that book. ";
    string const inText4 = "She's reading. ";
    string const inText5 = "He's reading. ";
    string const inText6 = "READ. ";
    string const inText7 = "Reading. ";

    string inText8=inText1+inText2+inText3+inText4+inText5+inText6+inText7;

    string::size_type dotpos = inText10.find(".");
    if(dotpos != string::npos)
        inText10.insert(dotpos, endl);


    cout << inText10 << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `inText10`? It's not defined in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming inText10 is just inText8, this is the working code.

Changes done:

1. Earlier, the inText10 string was not found. So, insert() on that object might have produced your error.
2. The position to insert newline is **NOT** dotpos. Its **dotpos + 1**
3. Note this code just adds a newline after finding the first dot. To add newline after every dot, use while loop to find all dots and insert newline char next to it.

   ```
   #include<iostream>
   #include<string>
   using namespace std;

   int main ()
   { 
      string const inText1 = "I'm reading. ";
      string const inText2 = "I like to read. ";
      string const inText3 = "I'm gonna read that book. ";
      string const inText4 = "She's reading. ";
      string const inText5 = "He's reading. ";
      string const inText6 = "READ. ";
      string const inText7 = "Reading. ";

     string inText8=inText1+inText2+inText3+inText4+inText5+inText6+inText7;

     string::size_type dotpos = inText8.find(".");
     if(dotpos != string::npos)
       inText8.insert(dotpos + 1, "\n");


     cout << inText8 << endl;
     return 0;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of undefined variables in your code, but basically you receive 'no matching member function for call to 'insert'' because you are trying to insert std::endl into a string. std::endl can't be casted to char of any type, so, you can't do this.

To fix your issue, replace

```
inText10.insert(dotpos, endl);
```

with

```
inText10.insert(dotpos, '\n');
```

By the way, if you want to insert \n after every single dot, you should do find() in a loop, since find() returns a single matched char position, not an array.

To learn more, why you can't insert std::endl, read this [std::endl description at cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl)